# Banking system using HashMap and Linked list

Tags: java, io, linked-list, hashmap

If anyone could give me some guidance on how to proceed I'm, trying to get it so that in the EnterTransaction jpane, - once the user has entered the relevant information including the accountID, the date time is to be that when the transaction is created (using java.util.Date) and also, once the account ID has been entered the name of the account holder, and all their details should be displayed, and the amount of the transaction is to be entered (where negative numbers debit from the account)

Questions:
-Is a linked list and a hashmap the best way to collect the client and transaction data?

-Reached a complete block on the createCustomerAccount and enterTransaction method, not too sure what i'm doing wrong/what i'm doing - any help at all would be great

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame {
// data fields
private ArrayList<Client> clientCollection = new ArrayList<Client>();
private JPanel contentPane;

HashMap<String,CurrentAccount> CAccMap= new HashMap<String,CurrentAccount>(); //enter a key and get an output
LinkedList<Transaction> TransactionList=new LinkedList<Transaction>(); //for transactions
//myList.add("a");

//Launch the application.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainMenu frame = new MainMenu();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainMenu() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0, 0, 0));

    JButton btnReadClientData = new JButton("Read Client Data");
    btnReadClientData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                readClientData();
            }
        });
    contentPane.add(btnReadClientData);

    JButton btnCreateCurrentAccount = new JButton("Create Current Account");
    btnCreateCurrentAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                createCurrentAccount();
            }
        });
    contentPane.add(btnCreateCurrentAccount);

    JButton btnEnterTransaction = new JButton("Transaction");
    btnEnterTransaction.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                //enterTransaction();
            }
        });
    contentPane.add(btnEnterTransaction);
}

/*
public void enterTransaction()
{
String accountID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,"Enter valid accountID", "Add CurrentAccount", 0);
if(CAccMap.CAccMap(accountID)){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Account ID: " + accountID ,"Details",0);
CAccMap.getCurrentAccount(accountID);
}
else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No account Found " ,"Error",0);
}

}

//public void isCurrentAccount(accountID){
//  cAccMap(contains key(accountid)
//}

public void getCurrentAccount(String accountID){
CurrentAccount CAccMap = CurrentAccount.get(accountID);
Client C = CAccMap.getClient();
String famName = C.getFamilyName();
System.out.println(famName);
}
 */
public void readClientData() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
    int opt = chooser.showOpenDialog(this);
    if (opt == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // read data from file
        File infile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        System.out.println("Reading data from " + infile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infile));
            String line;

            int id = 1;
            line = rdr.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                processNewClient(id, line);
                id++;
                line = rdr.readLine();
            }

            rdr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Not Found",
                "Unable to open " + infile.getAbsolutePath(),
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

public void processNewClient(int id, String data) {

    String[] parts = data.split(" ");
    try {
        String familyName = parts[0];
        String firstName = parts[1];
        int houseNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        String postCode = parts[3];

        if(validateNewClient(familyName, firstName, houseNumber, postCode)){
            Client c = new Client(id, familyName, firstName, houseNumber,
                    postCode);
            System.out.println("Added " + c);
            clientCollection.add(id, c);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid house number",
            "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public boolean validateNewClient(String familyName, String firstName, int houseNumber, String postCode)
{

    if(familyName.equals (""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error, family Name not entered", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }

    else if(firstName.equals (""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error, First Name not entered", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    else if(houseNumber <= 0)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error, House number invalid", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    else if(postCode.equals (""))/*[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][0-9A-Z]? [0-9]{3}[A-Z]{4-5}*/
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error, Post code not in correct format", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}

public void createCurrentAccount() {
    Object[] clients = clientCollection.toArray();
    Client cl;

    Object clientObj = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Select client", "Add Current Account", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, clients, clients[0]);
    cl = (Client) clientObj;
    System.out.println("Selected " + cl);
    String sortCode = "01-02-03";
    String accountID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
            "Enter valid accountID", "Add CurrentAccount", 0);

    if (Account.validateID(accountID))  {
        CurrentAccount ca = new CurrentAccount(cl,accountID, sortCode, 0);
        CAccMap.put(accountID,ca);//Using the .put method any newly created accounts are added to the hashmap and linked with their client
        System.out.println("Account Created");

    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid account ID " + accountID,
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

}

}

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Questions are up now, sorry about that

Comment: it's the createCurrentAccount method that i can't get to add the accountID and the client ca to the collection
it's the for loop that shouldn't be there, but i have no idea what to put there instead

Comment: if (accountID = e.getKey()) should be if (accountID.equals(e.getKey())) right now you are just reassigning accountId

Comment: it should be the if statement validating at the start if it validates add it to the list else print out that error saying invalid

Comment: I would keep the GUI code completely separate from your code to manage the accounts and transaction.  You should be able to unit test you account/transaction without any GUI code being involved.  When you mix many concerns together you are likely to confuse yourself and others.

Comment: the spec for the assignment is to keep all the code in one class i believe - awful, i know

Comment: i have ammended the code for the create account and it is now working as intended
how can i get the EnterTransaction method to work?

Comment: how would i go about adding a hashmap with string account id and then an object. and creating a separate object to store the account details and debit values. else, I would just create a linked list of the account id, details, debit value objects.